# Is there any way to tell if someone has been running Ubuntu live on my computer?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, files

Is there any way to tell if someone has been running Ubuntu live on a computer? I am the one running ubuntu live on my computer and I just wanted to know if any files or anything else is being left on the host computer.

Comment: Nothing is left when you run live, if anything has not been changed on HDD deliberately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can disable the ability to boot to usb in the BIOS; and the put a BIOS password on to ensure it can't be changed.  You can also disable the usb ports completely depending on your hardware.